# AttributeError: 'SimpleImputer' object has no attribute 'mean'

Tags: python, numpy, data-preprocessing

I am trying to perform preprocessing on iris dataset but on the imputation step I get this error while using SimpleImputer to print the mean of every column.

here is the full code for reference. I am getting the error in last part.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import preprocessing

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
iris_normalized = preprocessing.normalize(iris.datadata,norm='l2')
print(iris_normalized.mean(axis=0))

enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
iris_target_onehot = enc.fit_transform(iris.target.reshape(-1,1))
print(iris_target_onehot.toarray()[[0,50,100]])


X[:50,:] = np.nan
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
iris_imputed = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')
iris_imputed.fit_transform(X)
print(iris_imputed.mean(axis=0))
```

Sorry I am new to Machine Learning.

Comment: Did you read the imputer docs?

Answer (score 0):

Just save the fit_transform to iris_imputed before calling its mean. It will work

iris_imputed = iris_imputed.fit_transform(iris.data)